# No llega a finalizar el proceso

Tags: java, windows10

estoy ejecutando youtube-dl usando java. Pero al intentar bajar un video de youtube, normalmente no llega a terminar el proceso, se queda con el fichero .part o cosas asi. Incluso con 0 bytes de tamaño el archivo .temp. En cambio, si en el terminal ejecuto la linea directamente, siempre funciona correctamente. ¿Puede ser que tal vez se cierre el proceso antes de que termine la descarga del video o algo asi?. Es como si no le diese tiempo a terminar el proceso, no se.Gracias.

```
try {
        String direccionYoutube = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=direccionInventadaYoutube";
        String cmd = "\"" + "c:\\programa\\youtube-dl.exe" + "\"" + " " + direccionYoutube;
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
```

Comment: has probado a poner un pause en el cmd cuando lo ejecutas? También creo que te falta pasarle el parametro /C al cmd de manera que quedaria asi: String cmd = "cmd /C c:\\programa\\youtube-dl.exe" + "\"" + " " + direccionYoutube;

Comment: Sigue quedandose atascado igualmente.

Comment: y con el pause, que aparece en la ventana de cmd?

Comment: es que parece que no llegue a terminar la descarga por alguna razon, no se

Comment: ya he encontrado tu fallo, he conseguido hacerlo por c# pero entiendo que es lo mismo: String cmd = "/C c:\\programa\\youtube-dl.exe " + direccionYoutube;

Comment: @Guillem por favor publica tu comentario como respuesta.

Comment: `código` 
"/C c:\programa\youtube-dl.exe" https://www.youtube.com/v=direccionInventadaYoutube
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""/C": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es precisamente el que planteas en tu pregunta:

> ¿Puede ser que tal vez se cierre el proceso antes de que termine la descarga del video o algo así?

La respuesta es: **si**.

**PROBLEMA**

Se llama a la ejecución de un programa externo (que realiza una tarea), desde una aplicación Java y la aplicación Java se cierra antes que el programa externo finalice su operación.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La llamada a un proceso externo desde Java, se ejecuta de forma sincrónica. Es decir, Java no espera que la ejecución del programa o proceso externo finalice, a menos que le digas **explícitamente** que debe esperar. Una vez que el proceso finaliza, Java continuará con la ejecución del resto de procedimientos.

Esto lo logras usando un método de la clase `Process`. El método es `waitFor()`.

Para poder usar este método, debes instanciar una clase `Process` que se va a encargar de ejecutar tu comando o script externo.

La documentación de la Clase `Process` la consigues en [Oracle - Java Language - Class Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

La documentación del método `waitFor()` la consigues en [Oracle - Java Language - Class Process - Method: waitFor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor())

Una forma en la que puedes implementar tu programa usando la Clase `Process` y el método `waitFor()` es la siguiente:

```java
import java.io.*;

public class PruebaWaitFor {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      //Normalmente me gusta separar las cosas para poder reutilizar
      //Por ejemplo, puedes pasar el URL de YouTube como argumento y capturarlo luego en esta variable.
      //Aquí simplemente lo 'hardcodeo'
      String youTubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?ALGUN_VIDEO_TUYO_QUE_HAYAS_SUBIDO_A_YOUTUBE";
      // RECUERDA QUE NO ES LEGAL DESCARGAR CONTENIDO DE YOUTUBE A MENOS QUE SEAS EL DUEÑO O TENGAS PERMISO EXPLICITO
      // Ahora puedes declarar el comando que se ejecutará en la llamada al proceso:

      // En entorno Windows:
      String downloadHelper = "c:\\programa\\youtube-dl.exe";
    
      //Si eres usuario UNIX/LINUX/macOS:
      // String downloadHelper = "youtube-dl";
          
      // Ahora construimos nuestro comando
      String cmd = downloadHelper + " " + youTubeURL;
    
      // La siguiente variable almacenará la información
      // que el programa (youtube-dl) devuelve a la cónsola.
      // Así podremos mostrarla en nuestro entorno de ejecución.
      String linea;

      // Comenzamos
      System.out.println("Iniciando descarga...");
          
      // Aqui declaramos nuestra variable como tipo Proceso
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
          
      // Ahora declaramos un lector para poder almacenar
      // la información que sea enviada a la cónsola por 'youtube-dl'
      BufferedReader lecturaProceso = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
          
      // Ahora volcamos a la consola de Java cada línea capturada, así podremos ver el progreso
      while((linea = lecturaProceso.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(linea);
      }
          
      // Por último, la siguiente línea es la más importante
      // Aqui le decimos a Java que debe esperar que el Proceso 'p'
      // debe terminar antes de continuar cualquier otra instrucción

      // almacenamos el valor que arroja 'waitFor()'
      int exitEval = p.waitFor();
          
      // Si el Proceso 'p' terminó correctamente, entonces exitEval debe ser 0.
      if (exitEval == 0) {
        System.out.println("\nDescarga finalizada.\n");
      } else {
        // Aquí manejas lo que harás si algo falla
        System.out.println("Descarga fallida.\nAlgo ha ido mal.\n");
      }

      // La siguiente línea se imprimirá al finalizar todo el proceso.
      // Eso es lo que hace el método 'waitFor', espera que 'p' finalice
      // antes de seguir con la ejecución.
      System.out.println("Recuerda: No es legal descargar videos de Youtube a menos que seas el dueño del video");

    // Ahora capturamos las excepciones
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Como puedes ver en el código descrito anteriormente, he puesto las advertencias necesarias sobre la descarga de videos de YouTube.

Este es un extracto los términos y condiciones del sitio Youtube: [TOS - Castellano](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms&hl=es&gl=ES)

> 9. Contenidos de YouTube en el Sitio Web
>
> 9.1 A excepción del Contenido proporcionado al Servicio por Ud.,, todos los demás Contenidos del Servicio serán propiedad de YouTube, o le corresponderán en virtud de una licencia, y estarán sujetos a derechos de autor, derechos de marca y otros derechos de propiedad intelectual e industrial de YouTube o de los licenciantes de YouTube. Todas las marcas comerciales y de servicio de otros terceros presentes en los Contenidos no subidos o publicados por Ud. serán marcas comerciales y de servicio de sus respectivos propietarios.
>
> 9.2 Dicho Contenidos no podrán ser descargados, copiados, reproducidos, distribuidos, transmitidos, difundidos, mostrados, vendidos, otorgados bajo licencia o explotados para ningún otro fin sin el previo consentimiento por escrito de YouTube, o de los licenciantes de YouTube, en caso de que fuera aplicable. YouTube y sus licenciantes se reservan todos los derechos que no hayan sido expresamente otorgados con respecto a su Contenido.

Espero que la duda te quede aclarada.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan detallada y buena respuesta. Y gracias por avisarme acerca de youtube sus terminos legales. Si, obviamente es solo teoricamente y aprendiendo acerca de java y la ejecucion de comandos en general. Y no descargar sus videos.

Answer (score 1):

Añado mi comentario como respuesta,
Lo hice en C# y me funcionó, pero entiendo que es lo mismo

```
try {
        String direccionYoutube = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=direccionInventadaYoutube";
        String cmd = "/C c:\\programa\\youtube-dl.exe " + direccionYoutube;
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
```

Espero te sea de utilidad